# How to use onclick in React Threejs for a loaded GLTF object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, onclick, gltf

The GLTF file is loaded and looks nice, but I want to click on it and see if it has any information for example an uuid. The code below trickers a bug, saying TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined, when I click on the viewer. Can anybody tell me why this.mouse.x gives me an error and how I can click on the loaded GLTF objects and receive some piece of information from it? I have added the code below and a copied the error below as well. Hope that someone can help me out here.

TypeError: Cannot set property 'x' of undefined
HTMLCanvasElement.onClick C:/Users/alikuc/Desktop/codingProjects/IFCtoFSO/server-react/client/src/components/Viewer.js:65
62 |        function onClick(event) {
63 |            event.preventDefault();
64 |
65 |            this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
| ^
|            this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
67 |
68 |            this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';
import filePath from '../assets/02.00.04_test8.gltf';

export default class Viewer extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {

        //Add Scene
        this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

        //Add Renderer
        this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
        this.renderer.setClearColor('#808080');
        this.renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        this.renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
        this.renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        this.mount.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

        //Add Camera
        const fov = 60;
        const aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        const near = 1.0;
        const far = 1000.0;
        this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
        this.camera.position.set(45, aspect, 1, 1000);

        // //Add Geometry and material
        // const cube = new Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: '#0F0' }));

        // // //Add mesh which is also the model
        // this.scene.add(cube);
        
        
        // Load GLTF file
        // Instantiate a loader
        const loader = new GLTFLoader();

        /// Load a glTF resource
        loader.load(
            filePath,
            (gltf) => {
                this.scene.add(gltf.scene);
            },
            (xhr) => {
                console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total) * 100 + '% loaded');
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('An error happened');
                console.log(error);
            }
        );

        //Add raycaster to for interactivity
        this.raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        this.mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

        this.renderer.domElement.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);

        function onClick(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            this.mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
            this.mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

            this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouse, this.camera);

            var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(this.scene.children, true);

            if (intersects.length > 0) {
                console.log('Intersection:', intersects[0]);
            }
        }

        //Settings
        //Add Camera Controls
        const controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
        controls.addEventListener('change', this.render); // use if there is no animation loop
        controls.minDistance = 2;
        controls.maxDistance = 10;
        controls.target.set(0, 0, -0.2);
        controls.update();

        ///Add AMBIENT LIGHT
        let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
        light.position.set(20, 100, 10);
        light.target.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        light.castShadow = true;
        light.shadow.bias = -0.001;
        light.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
        light.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;
        light.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
        light.shadow.camera.far = 500.0;
        light.shadow.camera.near = 0.5;
        light.shadow.camera.far = 500.0;
        light.shadow.camera.left = 100;
        light.shadow.camera.right = -100;
        light.shadow.camera.top = 100;
        light.shadow.camera.bottom = -100;
        this.scene.add(light);
        light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.7);
        this.scene.add(light);

        //Start animation
        this.start();
    }

    //Unmount when animation has stopped
    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.stop();
        this.mount.removeChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    }

    //Function to start animation
    start = () => {
        //Rotate Models
        if (!this.frameId) {
            this.frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        }
    };

    //Function to stop animation
    stop = () => {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameId);
    };

    //Animate models here
    animate = () => {
        //ReDraw scene with camera and scene object
        //if (this.cubeMesh) this.cubeMesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
        this.renderScene();
        this.frameId = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
    };

    //Render the scene
    renderScene = () => {
        if (this.renderer) this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                style={{ width: '800px', height: '800px' }}
                ref={(mount) => {
                    this.mount = mount;
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 is it better now? Or does the error need to be formatted in a better way. Just copy pasted the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the scope of `this` changes when you're inside the `onClick` function.

Try adding `this` to that function's scope by adding `.bind(this)`

`this.renderer.domElement.addEventListener('click', onClick.bind(this), false);`

Comment: thanks it worked! Would you recommend me to use this.camera this.scene etc. or should I change the syntax to be let or const? I mean onclick.bind(this) is something I have never seen before and maybe the way I am doing it is unusual?

Comment: @Ali91 If you're going to use those objects throughout your `Component`, then it's important to keep `this.camera` (since you need it in `renderScene()`). If you're only using it inside a single function, and not in multiple parts of the `Component` lifecycle, then you can use `let` or `const`. Looks like you're already doing it the right way.